# How is it not a contradiction that it is possible to build fault tolerant circuits with strictly contractive (e.g.: depolarizing noise) channels?

Tags: quantum-gate, error-correction, quantum-operation, fault-tolerance

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105141) discusses strictly contractive channels, i.e. channels that strictly decrease the trace distance between any two input quantum states.

It is shown that if a quantum circuit is composed of rounds of gates followed by strictly contractive channels then the trace distance between any two input states would decay exponentially with circuit depth, which means we would not be able to distinguish outputs corresponding to any two different inputs.

In light of this, how is it even possible to build any kind of fault-tolerant circuit which is capable of "arbitrarily long" computations, given that the standard noise model, the depolarizing channel, is strictly contractive?

Comment: Because measurements **with** post-selection can be non-contractive (they aren't even CP maps since they are nonlinear).

Comment: But aren't there fault tolerant schemes that do not even use post-selection?

Comment: @keisuke.akira There is no post-selection in error correction.

Comment: A partial answer is that the definition of strictly contractive in the paper is unsuitable. They define a strictly contractive channel as one that contracts trace distance by a constant factor (independent of system size), which does not hold for standard noise models. For example, a channel that depolarizes each qubit with a probability $p$ is strictly contractive in the sense that $||T\rho-T\sigma||\leq k||\rho-\sigma||$, but only for $k=\exp(-pn)$, where $n$ is the number of qubits. Taking $k$ constant is too strong an assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. Indeed, CP maps - and this includes the operations  used in the error correction (measurement and subsequent unitaries) - will always decrease the trace norm.

The answer is that if you take a (strictly) contractive map on, say, a qubit, and consider how it acts if you apply it to many qubits, there will always be some subspace where the map is *much* less contractive - still contractive, but supressed exponentially.  The art of (quantum) error correction is to encode the information in those subspaces, and to "re-focus" it into those subspaces (which is the actual error correction procedure).

Let me give a (slightly oversimplified) example.

Consider a noise which flips a bit with probability $\epsilon=0.01$ (per unit time, if you wish).

Now encode a (classical) bit in $N$ zeros or $N$ ones, $0\cdots 0$ and $1\cdots 1$. Then, these states (seen as quantum states, if you wish, or as probability distributions) will keep a trace distance on the order of at most $\epsilon^{-N/2}$ -- after all, you have to flip half the bits in either to get *any* overlap between them (and if they are orthogonal, the trace distance stays 1).

So what happened?  Before, the noise was $\epsilon=0.01$.  Now, the noise is $\epsilon=0.01^{-N/2}$.  So for $N=10$, you might be able to go about $10^{10}$ time steps, rather than $100$.

Of course, this will break down if you let more time pass -- so what you have to do after a short interval of time is to "re-focus" your information, that is, move it back to that subspace which is best protected (like all zeros and all ones).  This is what error correction does. This is a CP map and does not increase distinguishability, but it will allow you to stay with the best error rate of $1$ error in $10^{10}$.

(Note: Clearly, this is not a way to safely encode quantum information - this is not what this example is supposed to illustrate.)

Comment: In the example, if we consider N=2 then the |00><00| state will be mapped to $(1-\epsilon)^2 |00><00| + \epsilon(1-\epsilon) |01><01| + \epsilon(1-\epsilon) |10><10|+\epsilon^2|11><11| $, similarly for |11><11|. summing up the terms, we get that after the channel, the trace distance is (1-2epsilon), Note that the N=1 case is contracted after the channel by (1- 2 epsilon). Thus, adding one more qubit did not exponentially suppress the contraction, it seems.

Comment: I believe in the same paper, it is shown that if one depolarizing channel contracts the trace distance by (1-p), having two parallel depolarizing channels will still contract it by (1-p). Isn't it true that the strictly contractive channel should contract all subspaces (like if we assume it is acting on a set of basis for one subspace)?

Comment: @Dina My argument is meant in the large N limit.  Also, note that the exponent is N/2, so N=2 will indeed not help.  And no, that's exactly the point: There are states which stay more orthogonal than others if you apply the same channel to every qubit.  More formally, if you have a channel $$E(\rho) = (1-p)\rho + p\,I/2\ ,$$ then $E\otimes E$ is ***not*** of the form $(1-q)\rho + q\,I/4$.  Why don't you do the example for, say 4 or 6 qubits?  (Note that this example is entirely classical and works for probability distributions.)

Comment: @Dina Can you point out where this is said in said paper?

Comment: It is on equation (27) and the paragraph following it. I guess trying out the 4 qubit case, the overall contraction coefficient may be a bit larger than 1-2epsilon. I don't know whether this is sufficient, since trace distance will still decay exponentially with depth, just with slower decay.

Comment: However, if $K$ is the contraction coefficient for the channel $E^{\otimes n}$, i.e., $||E^{\otimes n}(\rho)-E^{\otimes n}(\sigma)||/||\rho-\sigma||\leq K$, for all $\rho,\sigma$ including those in any subspace, then each subspace or set of states must be contracted by at least $K$. The question is what is $K$ in terms of the contraction for the individual channel $E$ .

Comment: Another resolution to the problem may be, as mentioned in the paper, that $T\otimes T$ may not be strictly contractive even if $T$ is strictly contractive, as long as $T$ is nonunital. May be the circuit has to be designed such that the noisy channel along with the measurements are not unital.

Answer (score 0):

So that's where quantum error correction comes in. By measuring the stabilizers, the code is projected back into a pure state. I'll give an example using a Bell state:

Imagine the state
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle),$$

which is stabilized by XX and ZZ (meaning we can catch errors by verifying that these two operators have eigenvalue +1 on our state). Now imagine that the state undergoes a stochastic X channel on the second qubit, described by:

$$E(\rho) = (1-p)I\rho I + p X_2\rho X_2.$$

The overall state will now become a mixed state described by:
$$\rho = \frac{1}{2}[(1-p)(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)(\langle 00| + \langle 11|) + p(|01\rangle + |10\rangle)(\langle 01| + \langle 10|)].$$
This state is a mixed state with trace less than 1, since the error channel is non-unitary.

When we measure the stabilizers XX and ZZ, we either get [+1, +1] with probability $1+p$, meaning that we have projected ourselves back into the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$, or with probability $p$ we get [+1, -1], meaning the state is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle + |10\rangle)$. Both of these new states are again pure states, and the goal of error correction is to be able to figure out what errors we have projected onto the state, so we can undo it and recover our state. The key point is that by measuring stabilizers, error correction naturally relies on a non-unitary process in order to deal with these trace reduction concerns.

Comment: But isn't trace distance non-increasing under the action of any quantum channel (whether it is unitary or not)?

Comment: The trace gets renormalized, or at least that's how I think about it. Lets say you are given a mixed state $\rho = 0.5 |0\rangle\langle 0| + 0.5 |1\rangle\langle 1|$, this state is mixed, but if you measure it and get a 0, your state is now $\rho' = |0\rangle\langle 0|$. By measuring and applying classical corrections, we can project and then get back to a cleaner state.

Comment: But you will only get the cleaner state |0><0| with probability 1/2, so really the projective measurement maps the state to 1/2 |0><0|+1/2|1><1|. I think what you describe is probably true, however if we describe all operations by quantum channels, which cannot increase the trace distance, a more subtle argument is needed to explain why QEC works.

Comment: I think the issue is this claim about being unable to increase trace distance. If you look in these notes (https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs191/fa14/lectures/lecture89.pdf), and look at the postmeasurement state, you'll notice the normalization factor. This factor is the part that allows measurements to "increase" the trace distance, and they renormalize the state when a measurement occurs.

Comment: @DriptoDebroy Without postselection, you cannot increase trace distance. If you measure and then do a conditional operation (and then forget the measurement result, if you want), this is a CPTP map.

Comment: I think I must not be thinking about this correctly, will have to do some reading!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Norbert (https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13249/12213) is great, as it explains why quantum computing can work under depolarizing noise (defined as each qubit getting depolarized at some rate).

However, the paper cited by OP considers an unusual definition of strictly contractive that in fact does not include depolarizing noise, because they consider $T$ to be strictly contractive if
$$||T\rho-T\sigma|| \leq k ||\rho-\sigma||,\qquad k<0$$
for constant $k$.

The standard definition of strictly contractive would be
$$||T\rho-T\sigma|| < ||\rho-\sigma||.$$
Single-qubit depolarizing noise is strictly contractive only according to the second condition, as the example given by Norbert illustrates. In the first definition we would have to take $k=\exp(-pn)$, where $n$ is the number of qubits and $p$ the probability for a qubit to be depolarized.